# Como hacer que un programa terminer con una palabra específica

Tags: c++

Como veis he intentado hacer un programa que cree un ejercicio para practicar las tablas de multiplicacion con el objetivo de practicar los numeros aleatorios, al principio no me dio ningun problema, pero intente hacer que el programa terminara una vez el usuario escribiese "terminar" y a parte que saliese dos contadores para ver los resultados.

```
cout<<"Practica de tablas de multiplicar"<<endl;
cout<<"\nEscribe terminar para terminar y mostrar el numero de aciertos y errores"<<endl;   

int n1=0,n2=0,resultado=0,aciertos=0,fallos=0;
char terminar[8];
do{

srand(time(NULL));
n1=0 + rand() % (11);
n2=0 + rand() % (11);

do{
cout<<n1<<"*"<<n2<<"= ";cin>>resultado;

if(resultado!=(n1*n2))
{cout<<"Resultado incorrecto"<<endl;
fallos++;}
else 
{cout<<"Resultado correcto"<<endl;
aciertos++;}
}while(resultado!=(n1*n2));}while(resultado!="terminar");
cout<<"Recuento:"<<endl<<"Aciertos"<<aciertos<<endl<<"Fallos"<<fallos;
getch();
return 0;
}"
```

El error que me da es este:

> [Error] ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

y se que es por intentar poner un entero (resultado) con un char (terminar)
pero no se como solucionarlo.

Agradecería mucho si me decís como transformar esto

```
while(resultado!="terminar")"
```

para que funcione

Comment: Como estas pidiendo los datos?

Comment: Se genera un numero aleatorio y se genera otro aleatoria, el usuario introduce un resultado, si es correcto se generan otros dos numeros,y si no pues le va a seguir repitiendo con los mismos numeros hasta que acierte, es decir el unico valor que introduce el ususario es el resultado y la palabra terminar para parar el programa(aunque eso es lo que quiero saber como se hace XD)

Answer (score 2):

```
while (resultado != "terminar");
```

Esa instrucción no tiene ni pies ni cabeza.

`resultado` es un entero:

```
int n1=0,n2=0,resultado=0,aciertos=0,fallos=0;
//            ^^^^^^^^^
```

Si tu idea es que el usuario pueda introducir una cadena o un número puedes probar a hacer esto:

```
int resultado;
std::string cadena;

do
{
  bool esNumero = true;
  std::cin >> resultado;
  if( std::cin.fail() )
  {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin >> cadena;
    esNumero = false;
  }

  if( esNumero )
  {
    if(resultado!=(n1*n2))
    // ...
  }
} while( cadena != "terminar" );
```

Lo que hace, básicamente, es intentar leer un entero. Si la lectura falla entonces es porque el usuario no ha escrito dígitos numéricos... se limpian entonces los flags de error de `cin` y se vuelca el dato en un `std::string`.

**Nota:** si no se limpian los flags de error `cin` se bloqueará en la siguiente lectura y el programa fallará.

Entonces, en función de si se ha leído un número o una cadena, se redirigirá la ejecución del código a donde corresponda... y así hasta que se introduzca el texto `"terminar"`

Comment: Ya lo dije,pero cuando me editaron la pregunta me borraron esa parte porque si... era producto de una desesperacion pero lo puse igualmente para que vieraís lo que intenba hacer aunque en el fondo no tiene logica.Basicamente quiero que el porgrama detecte cuando el usuario escribe "terminar" y cuando lo escriba se salga del bucle en el cual le espera el cout para mostrar los contadores.

Comment: @Nanozet el código de mi respuesta, en teoría, hace justamente eso

Answer (score 0):

No podes comparar un string con una variable así (de esa manera estas comparando el puntero), tenes que usar las funciones que te brinda la librería `string.h`.

Deberías hacerlo así:

```
while (strcmp(terminar, "terminar") != 0) {
    /* Procesar */  
}
```

Además fijate que definiste el arreglo terminar con una longitud de 8 y esto no te deja lugar para el `\0` que deben tener los strings para indicar el corte de la cadena. Debería ser de 9 `char terminar[9];`.

Comment: Si no fuese porque `resultado` es un `int`...

Comment: En vez de resultado es terminar, escribí mal la variable. Ya está editado.

Comment: fijate en el tamaño y en los usos de esa variable... esa solucion tampoco va a funcionar asi tal cual

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto:

```
//...
aciertos++;}
}while(resultado!=(n1*n2));}while(!to_string(resultado).compare("terminar"));
cout<<"Recuento:"<<endl<<"Aciertos"<<aciertos<<endl<<"Fallos"<<fallos;
//...
```

Lo que hace es convertir el resultado a `string` para compararlo con "terminar".

Comment: `std::string` ya tiene el operador de comparación sobrecargado... no hace falta llamar a `compare`. El código es más engorroso

Comment: Por otro lado tu respuesta podría llegar a ser válida si no fuese por un detalle tonto... `resultado` es un `int` y dificilmente vas a poder igualarlo a `"terminar"`